# ReactJS w/ Inertia - calling onClick function multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inertiajs

## Problem

I am attempting to make a dynamic content box to incrementally fill in a form in ReactJS. As part of this, I simply want a box/area that changes its content when the user clicks 'Next' or 'Prev'.

The problem I appear to be facing is that the onClick method is getting called multiple times (obviously - I've only clicked it once).

I have a MWE below to demonstrate the problem I'm facing.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default function Test () {

    const [section, setSection] = useState(1);
    const [sectionContent, setSectionContent] = useState();

    useEffect( ()=>{
        console.log("ENTRY useEffect");
        if (section == 1) {
            setSectionContent(<div>Details</div>);
        }
        else if(section == 2){
            setSectionContent(<div>Advanced Details</div>);
        }
        else if(section == 3){
            setSectionContent(<div>Super Advanced Details</div>);
        }
        console.log("EXIT useEffect");
    },[section]);


    function gotoPrevSection(){
        console.log("ENTRY gotoPrevSection");
        if(section == 1){
            setSection(1);
        }
        else if(section == 2){
            setSection(2);
        }
        console.log("EXIT gotoPrevSection");
    }

    function gotoNextSection(){
        console.log("ENTRY gotoNextSection");
        if (section == 1) {
            setSection(2);
        }else if(section == 2){
            setSection(3);
        }
        console.log("EXIT gotoNextSection");
    }

    return (
        <>
            {sectionContent}
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => gotoPrevSection()}>
                    Prev
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => gotoNextSection()}>
                    Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Opening the page, we have 'Details' and the 'Prev' and 'Next' buttons. When I click 'Next' I skip all the way to the 'Super Advanced Details' section - skipping the middle section !
The console log looks like this:

```
[Log] ENTRY gotoNextSection 
[Log] EXIT gotoNextSection 
[Log] ENTRY useEffect 
[Log] EXIT useEffect 
[Log] ENTRY gotoNextSection 
[Log] EXIT gotoNextSection 
[Log] ENTRY useEffect 
[Log] EXIT useEffect 
[Log] ENTRY gotoNextSection 
[Log] EXIT gotoNextSection
```

You can clearly see that the 'gotoNextSection' method is called *three* times even though it's only clicked once. What am I doing wrong ?

### What I've tried

I am aware of the need for the onClick portion to look like `onClick={() => function()}` rather than just `onClick=function()`. This isn't the problem - the method isn't getting called straight away otherwise the details page wouldn't be static and stable - it's only when clicking this occurs.

I am React 17.0.2.

The Inertia init looks like:

```
createInertiaApp({
  title: title => `${title} - ${appName}`,
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/Test.js`),
  setup({ el, App, props }) {
    return render(<App {...props} />, el);
  },
});
```

What is going on here? Is this a React bug in the newer version ?

Answer (score 1):

The Ghost option in Browsersync (that is included in Laravel Mix) is causing this.

Disable it to stop button double clicking ! browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-ghostMode

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your functions as below, and introduce a `totalSection` constant.

In addition, you should be using useMemo instead of useEffect for your type of use (you save one additional render).

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-violet-tzjbw?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";

const totalSections = 3;
export default function Test() {
  const [section, setSection] = useState(1);
  


  const sectionContent = useMemo(() => {
    if (section == 1) {
      return(<div>Details</div>);
    } else if (section == 2) {
      return(<div>Advanced Details</div>);
    } else if (section == 3) {
      return(<div>Super Advanced Details</div>);
    }


  },[section])

  function gotoPrevSection() {
    console.log("ENTRY gotoPrevSection");

    setSection((prev) => (prev === 1 ? totalSections : prev - 1));
    console.log("EXIT gotoPrevSection");
  }

  function gotoNextSection() {
    console.log("ENTRY gotoNextSection");
    setSection((prev) => (prev === totalSections ? 1 : prev + 1));

    console.log("EXIT gotoNextSection");
  }

  return (
    <>
      {sectionContent}
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => gotoPrevSection()}>Prev</button>
        <button onClick={() => gotoNextSection()}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for responding ! 

However, that still doesn't work on my local test environment. It fails in a different way than before. Because of the ```=== 1``` and ```=== totalSections``` parts you put in, sometimes on my local system the button click just doesn't appear to register (even though I can see in the logs it's called 3 times).

Both my original code and your code work fine on Codesandbox - but not locally - what on earth could be causing the weird click behaviour on my local system ?

Comment: Ok, I have played around a bit and managed to find out a little more. 

I mentioned Inertia - and I think this is where the error may be. In the current Laravel project, I just modified the templates a bit to manually include the webpack generated app.js - and it works. But as soon as Laravel + Inertia is brought into it, this behaviour is present. Interesting.

Comment: Never really worked with react + php before since I've always used node+react, so good luck figuring that part out...

Comment: No worries ! I understand. I'll try to keep documenting here what I find. 

So far I have narrowed it down to BrowserSync. The installation in my env causes this bug to happen.

Comment: Ok - solved ! (kinda). The Ghost option in Browsersync (that is included in Laravel Mix) is causing this. 

Disable it to stop button double clicking ! https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-ghostMode